# Is it better practice to count all rows, or store a variable in a related table representing the count of rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say business rules want to prevent the abuse of users storing too many rows in a table whatever those rows correspond to...

To enforce this rule, is it better to count all rows upon a CRUD operation and validate that a user has not exceeded the max amount of rows? Or would it be better to store an integer in a table and update that number as rows are either created or deleted?

Comment: I would do it dynamically because otherwise, you're depending on triggers and other logic to do what you could do (quickly) with a `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table`

Comment: You can build it into the INSERT itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not preferable to use count in a field itself, better to have count query and use it, By the chance if you have a field for count, and made any changes on the field will not get exact result what you are expecting. use count() query instead of storing in a field.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer. I'd recommend you start with simple, but be prepared to scale. That is, start with a count query against the live data to enforce your constraints, but abstract that away so the logic for counting is encapsulated.

As you scale, you might encounter any of these issues that require you denormalize to a stored value:

1. A table held on storage with enough rows to stress the underlying storage IOPS
2. A count query that requires non-trivial index scanning
3. A count query that runs so many times as to contend with write locks

If you switch to a stored value, you will have to balance the need for a precise up-to-the-second count with the cost to calculate that value. That is the real balance you're trying to achieve. Early on in development, the cost for calculating the count is trivial: as you scale, this is not the case. Plan for it with encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

You could create unique index on (business_column, version_num) and add check constraint on version column for example up to x. Then DB will enforce your rules.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    b_col INT,
    version_num INT,
    CHECK (version_num BETWEEN 1 AND 3),
    UNIQUE(b_col, version_num)
);

INSERT INTO tab(b_col, version_num)
VALUES (1, 1),(1,2),(1,3);

INSERT INTO tab(b_col, version_num)
VALUES (1,4);
-- CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_1` failed for `fiddle_CIHMJQBAGQNCFTVVIHZQ`.`tab`

INSERT INTO tab(b_col, version_num)
VALUES (2,1),(2,2);

SELECT *
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=1cce4b982cd5aae9e5bd3eb68fc21b59)**

Note: To enforce `CHECK` constraint you need to use `MySQL 8.0`/`MariaDB`.